# Cannot read property 'computeModPow' of undefined

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

After I've upgraded my project to react-native 0.64, aws amplify doesn't work properly. Mainly, I'm trying to make an authentification workflow, but the login functionality throws me the "Cannot read property 'computeModPow' of undefined", even if signup function works completely fine.

After digging into the problem, I found that "aws-cognito-identity-js" is the main problem. If I try to link the library, rn bundler throws an error, that "aws-cognito-identity-js" is already linked, or that I can't override it.

Any suggestions?

Package.json

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4",
"aws-amplify": "^1.1.32",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.15",
```

Implementation:

```
export const loginUser = (credentials: any) => async (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

  try {
    const data = await Auth.signIn(credentials.email, credentials.password);
    return loginUserSuccess(dispatch, data);
  } catch (error) {
    return loginUserFail(dispatch, error);
  }
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch: any, data: any) => {
  console.log({ data });
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, attributes: {} });
};

const loginUserFail = (dispatch: any, error: any) => {
  console.log({ error });
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAILED });
};
```

Error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'computeModPow' of undefined
    at BigInteger.nativeModPow [as modPow] (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:217690:17)
    at AuthenticationHelper.calculateA (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:217990:16)
    at AuthenticationHelper.getLargeAValue (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:217928:16)
    at new AuthenticationHelper (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:217910:12)
    at CognitoUser.authenticateUserDefaultAuth (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:219720:36)
    at CognitoUser.authenticateUser (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:219710:23)
    at blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:185525:14
    at tryCallTwo (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:24791:7)
    at doResolve (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:24955:15)
    at new Promise (blob:file:///6e426a68-ddf4-48ca-86cf-ba3536cb9a13:24814:5)"
```

Comment: You really should share the code, else how you expect help from others?

Comment: I don't think that this would help, it's a basic workflow, but ok

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, If you already know the answer of ur problem, probably wouldn't have to post here anyway?

Comment: @Isaac, I've updated the code, I hope it helps you

Comment: You tried install `webpack json-loader`??

Comment: I'm using react native, I don't think there is webpack

Comment: Plase refer https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Comment: @hongdevelop I've followed the docs, however, this is working just with react native 0.59-

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried to run `react-native link amazon-cognito-identity-js` according to https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react#add-auth.

However the `Cannot read property 'computeModPow' of undefined` error persisted even after cleaning the build, restarting packager, etc.

The problem was that the package never got linked properly with `react-native link amazon-cognito-identity-js`. This requires us to manually link which is pretty easy to do luckily!

Assuming XCode (Look [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-manually-1) to find how to do the similar process for Android) you go to the `Project Navigator` and right click `Libraries` folder which contains all your 3rd party .xcodeproj. Choose `Add Files...` and add the `RNAWSCognito.xcodeproj` from within the `${projectDir}/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/ios/` directory. Open the `RNAWSCognito.xcodeproj` and `Products` folders and drag `libRNAWSCognito.a` to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` under the General tab. Re-run the project and should be good to go. May have to clean, restart packager, etc.

[image: Image showing XCode Project Navigator with proper linking]

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by doing the following:

```
yarn add amazon-cognito-identity-js
react-native link amazon-cognito-identity-js
cd ios ; pod update ; cd ..
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who needs this, but after I confirmed amazon-cognito-identity-js:
1) was in settings.gradle
2) was in app/build.gradle

I had to make sure to have the below in `MainApplication.java`

`import com.amazonaws.RNAWSCognitoPackage;`

```
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()
                new NetInfoPackage(),
                new AsyncStoragePackage(),
                new RNAWSCognitoPackage()
        );
    }
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the below, restarted the server and it was good.

```
npm install --save amazon-cognito-identify-js --force
```